# Getting data from laravel eloquent with deeper relationship and display to the view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
      
  $suppliers = Supplier::with(
            [
                'purcheses' => function ($query) {
                    $query->with(
                        [
                            'payments' => function ($query) {
                                $query->sum('amount');
                            }
                        ]
                    )->get();
                }
            ]
        )->latest()->get();
```

I have a **suppliers** table with has-many **relations with purchases of purchases table** with has-many **relations with payments and payment belongs to purchases,** how to get the total sum of payment for each purchase that belongs to this supplier?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package might help you,

The [package's readme](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/blob/master/README.md) illustrates various types of relationships that this package supports:

- HasMany
- ManyToMany
- MorphMany
- MorphToMany
- MorphedByMany
- BelongsTo

Here's an example from the readme of a HasMany relationship for a complex relationship:

```
/*
 Country
   -> has many
 User
   -> has many
 Post
   -> has many
 Comment
*/
 
class Country extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
 
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Comment', ['App\User', 'App\Post']);
    }
}
 
// Access country comments
$country->comments();
```

In the above example, the package uses Eloquent conventions keys, and the package allows you to specify custom keys for local and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatmap) and [loadSum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions):

```
$suppliers = Supplier::with('purchases')
    ->get();

// Load the payments total for each purchase.
$suppliers
    ->flatMap
    ->purchases
    ->loadSum('payments', 'amount');

return $suppliers;
```